# What causes the imbalance where back points towards the side after serving?

Tags: tennis, technique, serve

I am analysing the serving [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1x-XAtmPDNk&t=2m30s) where the player gets angular momentum not towards the field but to the side.

[image]

[image]

where you see back pointing towards the side, bad. In comparison [Federer 1m12s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr07PuQojg0&t=1m12s) gets the momentum towards the field.

[image]

[image]

where you see the back pointing towards the back of the field after serving, good.

**Is the back direction after serving due to bad center of mass? How to fix it? And what is causing it with the red player?**

Answer (score 2):

It's the follow-through , the only way to fix it is to practice your serving motion and form

Comment: It is the follow-through, spot-on +1. **I suspect the reason for the swing is too tight rotator/shoulder cuff**: the massive rotational force spins the torso to the side in the point where the flexible shoulder cuff should make room for the motion...I think I better improve the rotator cuff flexibility before any further changes...

Comment: Quick tip: in-order for you to improve your shoulder swing , try practicing serve by being parallel to baseline , i've done it in my younger days , it can help you control and add more serving power and also improve your service motion

Comment: You mean legs parallel to the baseline and direction of the body after serving perpendicular to the baseline? My upper body analysis [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19404/6066) which I suspect causing the stiffness and so the extra unnecessary swing. I must get the flexibility better...trying to find solutions to rotator cuff flexibility...

Comment: regarding with that , when i was starting tennis in my younger days, i am having a hard time serving hard and according to my coaches that i had unnecessary movements and i needed whip motion for me to serve effectively, that's why they introduce me to that training and also squat training for the spring effect.

Comment: Excellent point about squats! And squats must be done with that kind of explosive power to use glycogen energy reserves (not long switch). I am building rotator cuff training to me -- and now I also need to do more explosive squats training -- that is so sure! The explosive jump/turn requires squats/explosiveness from all muscles (not just from upper body). I think I better start booty training -- **perhaps the swing is also due to imbalances due to muscles --> next more booty/squats/shoulder-cuff training**. Training [rotator cuff](http://www.pinterest.com/henrilosoi/rotator-cuff/).

Comment: Also I have S-shaped back, hunched back in the video -- which results into poor form. It can be improved by keeping the position better (middle part of body forward so breasts less hunced and back more straight).

Comment: I collected points so far emerging [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/7360/630), there is many little points to which I need to concentrate on my training -- amazing brainstorming. Big thanks for your contributions, I am starting to feel so motivated to my training again :D

Comment: Glad i could help, cheers for the discussion , i've learned alot. Keep Playing!

Comment: I created a video showing how I understand explosive [squats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dckzhtPCJI&t=1m16s) for improving the tennis serving :)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to summarise points emerging in the other answer and its comments. Video shows possible weaknesses in **Technique**

- legs parallel the baseline and direction of the motion perpendicular the baseline

which can be improved by

1. stiff shoulder cuff that requires shoulder cuff trainings like [here](http://www.pinterest.com/henrilosoi/rotator-cuff/)
2. hunched S-shaped back requires booty training like [here](http://www.pinterest.com/henrilosoi/booty-training/)
3. explosive serving requires explosive squats like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dckzhtPCJI&t=1m16s) where you use as many leg muscles as possible: use hypothrophy/power training using the glycogen energy reserves for the first serving while the second serving can be done with different technique with less power

[image]